# how to use static/inline error messages with jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to use `inline/static` error messages with `jquery.validate` - as in not-auto-generated:

```
<p>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name_input" name="name" required="required" data-message="we'd like to know your name" />
    <div for="name_input" class="error"><div class="arrow_tip_left"></div>did you forget your name?</div>
</p>

<p>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email_input" name="email" prompt="your email address" class="email" required="required" data-message="please enter a valid email address" />
    <div for="email_input" class="error"><div class="arrow_tip_left"></div>please enter a valid email</div>
</p>
```

How do I get `.validate()` to use the existing error messages rather than creating new ones?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well then it seems you dont need jquery validate. In jquery (not jquery validate) you can use [onblur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/), [onchange](http://api.jquery.com/change/)
and show your static error message when field is empty, not correct email address  etc.